# ImportError: No module named sendgrid local development server windows 10

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sendgrid

this is my code:

```
import sendgrid
from sendgrid import SendGridClient, Mail
import Message

s = sendgrid.SendGridClient("2HXwPrNlQX-5RBJ61webMA")
message = sendgrid.Mail()

message.add_to('Jhon Doe <jdoe@test.com>')
message.set_subject('Example')
message.set_html('Body')
message.set_text('Body')
message.set_from('Jhon Doe <jdoe@test.com>')
status, msg = sg.send(message)
print(status, msg)
```

I am install sendgrid

```
pip install -r requirements.txt

pip install sendgrid
pip install --upgrade sendgrid
pip install smtpapi
pip install --upgrade smtpapi
pip install python_http_client
pip install --upgrade python_http_client
```

When i run app
dev_appserver.py ./ --port=8081

Error: ImportError: No module named sendgrid

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in installing things with `pip` when you're using GAE. It runs in a sandbox, and doesn't look at the things installed outside there. As [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#adding_third_party_python_libraries) show, if you need to install a third-party app you need to copy or symlink the relevant modules into your app directory.

Answer (score 0):

Python App on App Engine

You can add a third-party library to your app in one of two ways: requesting the library or installing the library.

You can get the reference from link give below to **Installing a library**

[Reference Link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27)

Answer (score 0):

App Engine runs in a sandbox, so if you install new libraries globally, they aren't accessible to your app. That's because App Engine isn't going to upload all your local libraries, just your application ones.

You probably want to consider using [Darth Vendor](https://github.com/jonparrott/Darth-Vendor) or something similar. You install needed libraries *within the application* and then upload them *as part of your app*.